# Three-phase system with line-to-neutral voltage

Tags: power-electronics, electromagnetism

**I have the following problem:**

> Consider a three-phase system with *line-to-neutral* voltage `268 / 0 ° V`.
> It is Y-connected to a resistive load with `R=3Ohm per phase.`
> How much power does the load consume in kW (answer with one decimal).

Is the *line-to neutral* voltage the RMS-voltage?
 since `P=|VLN|⋅|I|⋅cos(φ)` I thought this could be calculated as I=268/30, V<sub>LN</sub>=268 V and cos(φ)=1 since there is no phase shift. So P for one phase would be `(268/30)⋅268⋅1 = 2394.13` and for a three-phase system: `3⋅2394.13=7182.4=7.2kW`
This is apparently incorrect... I would be thankful for some guidance to solve this problem.

Comment: I calculated it as (268² / 30) * 3, which still gives 7.2kW.  For resistive loads, the phase isn't important.

Comment: Yes, AC power voltages are always quoted in RMS but why are you dividing by 30? The resistance is 3 ohms. (SI standard recommends a space between the number and the unit same as in "5 nuts" rather than "5nuts". It helps avoid this sort of confusion. The ° symbol can be an exception and can be used with or without a space, I think.)